# Why in livewire inside of the method mount add a $this->emit('test'). The emit not start?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

Good morning, I have problems when issuing from the mount of livewire. I put it all in one file to make it easier to understand. If I leave it on render, the next action that happens on render executes the emit 2 times and then once accordingly. I'm asking if there is any way to emit on the mount.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Ministries\Uniform;

use Livewire\Component;

class Header extends Component
{
    public $listeners = [
        'test'
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->emit('test');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.ministries.uniform.header');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        logger('from mount');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. I remember to use defer loading to emit something. Add `wire:init="$emit('test')"` on the first element of your component's view, it will emit the event 'test' after both back and frontend are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

emit won't work in the mount function or render function (during the first load) as Livewire's javascript isn't running yet. But it will work in the render function on subsequent requests.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks